# Set `0` if json returns null

Tags: jquery, ternary-operator

I am showing json data in a div its working good.

```
var details= response.data.filters;
    $.each(details,function(i,value){
    $('.subSection').append('<section><label>Speed</label><label>'+value.speed+'</label></section>');
});
```

Here I am trying to show `0` when I get `value.speed` as `null`.So I tried using ternary operator like this

```
$('.subSection').append('<section><label>Speed</label><label>'+(value.speed==null)?'0':value.speed+'</label></section>');
```

But its returning continuously zeros like this..`0000`.Not a proper structured element.

I think I did something wrong in a ternary operator.Can anyone correct me if am wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try enclosing with brackets like,

```
$('.subSection').append('<section><label>Speed</label><label>'+((value.speed==null)?'0':value.speed)+'</label></section>');
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your order of operations, you need to wrap your entire ternary in parens.  Your statement effectively evaluates to:

```
$(".subSection").append(
  ("<section><label>Speed</label><label>" + (value.speed == null))
    ? "0"
    : (value.speed + "</label></section>")
);
```

Where what you want is:

```
$(".subSection").append(
  "<section><label>Speed</label><label>" +
    (value.speed == null ? "0" : value.speed) +
    "</label></section>"
);
```

Also you can probably replace the ternary with `(value.speed || '0')` which will use `'0'` if `value.speed` is any falsy value

In the future you're better off extracting statements rather than inlining them which prevents this issue altogether:

```
const speed = (value.speed == null) ? "0" : value.speed;
$(".subSection").append(
  "<section><label>Speed</label><label>" +
    speed +
    "</label></section>"
);
```